# look for regex find a word(5 characters) repeat 5 times in same line

Tags: java, regex

I work for some regular expressions to search for words in a text without using the Pattern and Matcher classes of java.util to run regular expressions. I am looking for a regex to find a complete word of at least five repeated 4 times on the same line characters.

For example the word "return" in this line: return on right, turn left, you have to go back again.

I know how to find a word of at least 5 characters \ b \ w {5} \ b but I'm stuck for the rest.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regular expression like this.

```
(\\b\\w{5}\\b)(?:.*?\\1){4}
```

**Note:** I used a non-capturing group above so if you need to change the amount of repeated times you can.

Explanation:

```
(             # group and capture to \1:
  \b          #   the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
  \w{5}       #   word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (5 times)
  \b          #   the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
)             # end of \1
(?:           # group, but do not capture (4 times):
  .*?         #   any character except \n (0 or more times)
  \1          #   what was matched by capture \1
){4}          # end of grouping
```